# Need to Show a message when DataList is Empty

Tags: asp.net, datalist, is-empty

I'm using DataList to show records on Client Site of my web page. I need to show a message when my DataList is empty. Is there a property of Datalist? How to show that message?

Comment: Funny enough, it seems not so. I was expecting some 'EmptyXXX' properties like the GridView has.

Answer (score 29):

`EmptyDataText` property is not supported by DataList yet. But you can achieve almost same functionality using the following trick:

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:Label Visible='<%#bool.Parse((DataList1.Items.Count==0).ToString())%>' 
               runat="server" ID="lblNoRecord" Text="No Record Found!"></asp:Label>
</FooterTemplate>
```

That is creating a Label in Footer of DataList, and make it visible only of DataList record count is 0.

Comment: Is there an update to this? When I tried this, it couldn't find the data list by its id.

Answer (score 0):

```
RowCount = Convert.ToInt32(DLMoreImages.Items.Count.ToString());
if (RowCount != null && RowCount < 1)
{
    DLMoreImages.Visible = false;
    LblerrorMess.Text = "No Record Found...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code

```
if( dataList.Items.Count == 0 )
{
    dataList.Visible = false;
    lblMessage.Visible = true;
    lblMessage.Text = "No Record Found.";
}
```

`lblMessage` is a label control which initially hidden, beneath the DataList.  You can write above code either in `OnDataBind` event or just after calling `dataList.DataBind()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
datalist.children.length === 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use parameters in C#:

```
concat(Product, @space ,Subname)
```

...

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@space", " ");
```