# How can I display "No Records found" in datalist?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datalist

This code seems simple enough on the surface but I am trying to display a message when no records are present in datalist.

I have this on markup:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CellPadding="4"
   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
   Font-Bold="False" OnSelected="SqlDataSource1_Selected" Font-Names="Verdana"
   Font-Size="Small" RepeatColumns="2"
   RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100%" ForeColor="#333333">
   <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
...
...
</asp:DataList>
<asp:label CssClass="Treb10Blue" ID="lblMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Then on codebehind, I have this:

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Selected

  If e.AffectedRows = 0 Then
      lblMsg.Visible = True
      lblMsg.Text = "No records found"
  Else
      lblMsg.Text = ""
  End If

End Sub
```

I am not getting any errors but the message is not displaying.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756466/need-to-show-a-message-when-datalist-is-empty)  that could help you

Comment: What *is* the value of "e.AffectedRows"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. A much easier solution than I would have imagined.

```
   <FooterTemplate>
     <asp:Label forecolor="#9ACD32" Visible='<%# IIF(DataList1.Items.Count=0 And ddlLocation.SelectedItem.Value<>"0", "True", "False")%>' runat="server" ID="lblMsg" Text="No records found"></asp:Label>
    </FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: Is there an update to this? When I tried this, it couldn't find the data list by its id.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excerpt from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourcestatuseventargs.affectedrows.aspx), maybe it's what you're seeing:

> All operations return the number of rows affected by the operation.
>   The AffectedRows property has the same value as the return value of
>   the Update, Insert, and Delete methods.
>
> When the **Select** method is called and the data source is set to
>   DataReader mode, **the return value is 0 in all cases**.

If that's the case, then maybe you can reverse your logic:

- by default, display the label with the 'No records found'
- create a handler for the the DataList's ItemDataBound event, and hide the label there (because in that case you have at least one record)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check the number of items in your DataList.  Try this:

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Selected

  If DataList1.Items.Count = 0 Then
      lblMsg.Visible = True
      lblMsg.Text = "No records found"
  Else
      lblMsg.Text = ""
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How can I tie your solution to dropdownlist control?

It works, sort of.

It displays that message whether there is value or not.

So, we have dropdownlist control with 4 options.

Perhaps if I can tie it to dropdownlist control, then if the value for the dropdownlist is 0 then then show the message.

Can you help with this?

Comment: Tie it to whatever your dropdown is called then.

Comment: I asked, can you please help?

That means that I don't know how. 

It is ok if you don't know how yourself but that was a non-answer.

Comment: How on earth would I know what you named your dropdown?

Comment: Just say you don't know how. Like I said, that's ok too.

You don't need to know the name. A sample of how to tie your code to any a dropdown would suffice.

My dropdown is called ddlLocation.